# How to return all values in for loop?

Tags: java, groovy

This groovy code I have running in FileMaker but the loop just returns one value how can i return all fileslist.
    In FileMaker println statements are doesn't working,only return statement working so how can I return all values
    like below loop displays.

```
        start()
        def start(){
        def store;
        def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
        ftpClient.connect(server)
        // println(ftpClient.replyString)
        ftpClient.login(user,pass)
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
        FTPFile[] fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/")
```

This loop just returns the only first value in FileMaker

```
        for(int i=0; i<fileslist.length; i++){  
          String file_name = fileslist[i].getName()
          String file_timestamp = fileslist[i].getTimestamp().getTime()
          return '|' + file_name+ '|' + '/' +file_name+'|' + '{' +file_timestamp+ '}' + '\n'      
         }     
        ftpClient.disconnect()
      }
```

How can I return all values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return as a long String, you need to make a list of strings in the loop and then, after the loop, concatenate and return them.

```
def allFiles = []; 
for(int i=0; i<fileslist.length; i++){  
  String file_name = fileslist[i].getName()
  String file_timestamp = fileslist[i].getTimestamp().getTime()
  String s = '|' + file_name+ '|' + '/' +file_name+'|' + '{' +file_timestamp+ '}'
  allFiles << s
}     
ftpClient.disconnect()
return allFiles.join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a list and return it.

```
start()
def start(){
  def store;
  def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
  ftpClient.connect(server)
  // println(ftpClient.replyString)
  ftpClient.login(user,pass)
  ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
  FTPFile[] fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/")

  // This loop just returns the only first value in FileMaker  
  List<String> mylist = new List<String>(); 
  for(int i=0; i<fileslist.length; i++){  
    String file_name = fileslist[i].getName()
    String file_timestamp = fileslist[i].getTimestamp().getTime()
    myList.add('|' + file_name+ '|' + '/' +file_name+'|' + '{' +file_timestamp+ '}');      
  }     
  ftpClient.disconnect()
  return myList;
}
```

You'll then have a short and easy access to all your values and you'll be able to access them separately to do whatever you need with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expressions. Short and simple.

```
List<String> allFiles = Arrays.stream(filelist)
    .map(f -> String.format(“| %s | /%s | { %s }”, f.getName(), f.getName(), f.getTimestamp().getTime()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```